# Media Query not responding in production: React 18 App

Tags: css, reactjs, media-queries, netlify, production

My media queries work in development, but when I go to view in production it does not respond to the font-size media queries. I am viewing the production build on an iPhone 13 and suspect the issue may be specifically for mobile devices only. I used React 18 for this project and deployed manually by dropping a build folder on Netlify.

I have the proper meta tag in my HTML,

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

I have a proper hierarchy for my media queries in CSS,

```
/* ////////////////// */
/* ! MEDIA QUERIES XS DEVICES */
/* ////////////////// */

@media (max-width: 380px) {
  .include span {
    word-spacing: 6px;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
  }

  .medium-contianer {
    font-size: 0.9rem;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 370px) {
  .medium-contianer,
  .strength,
  .bar-container {
    margin: 0 0.35rem;
    font-size: 0.85rem;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 330px) {
  .include span {
    word-spacing: 4px;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 320px) {
  .medium-contianer,
  .strength,
  .bar-container {
    margin: 0 0.35rem;
    font-size: 0.75rem;
  }

  .include span {
    word-spacing: 4px;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 300px) {
  .medium-contianer,
  .strength,
  .bar-container {
    margin: 0 0.1rem;
    font-size: 0.7rem;
  }

  .include span {
    word-spacing: 4px;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
  }
}

/* ////////////////// */
/* ! MEDIA QUERIES TABLET DEVICES */
/* ////////////////// */

@media (min-width: 550px) {
  .main-container {
    width: 80vw;
    margin: 2rem auto;
  }
}

/* ////////////////// */
/* ! MEDIA QUERIES DESKTOP DEVICES */
/* ////////////////// */

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .medium-contianer,
  .strength,
  .include span {
    font-size: 1.35rem;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 900px) {
  .main-container {
    width: 50vw;
    margin: 2rem auto;
  }

  .strength-container {
    height: 2rem;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1700px) {
  .main-container {
    width: 25vw;
    margin: 50rem auto;
    transform: scale(2);
  }
}
```

and in all Chrome dev tool media displays it is formatted exactly how I want. However, when I viewed the production build on my phone, none of the media queries remained intact.

[output on chrom dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mT5AK.png)

[output on my mobile device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dt0da.png)

link to my repo
https://github.com/cassius2828/password-generator/tree/main/src

link to deployed app
https://password-generator-creynolds.netlify.app/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is not your media queries (they're working just fine), it's more a cross-browser compatibility problem. I guess you have an iphone? Browsers unfortunately don't all work the same, even the same browser on two different devices (iOS vs Android for example).

Here are some details you could check out about cross-browser compatibility & why it exists: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Cross_browser_testing/Introduction

Do you have any ways to test your application on different devices before deploying your code in production? If so, I would highly recommend doing that and adjusting your css values accordingly.

My solution for you right now would be to start by lowering the left-right margins of .strength & .bar-container to see if it gives more space to the 'VERY STRONG' element so it could stay on one line. It would be a start!

And just because I'm here: you wrote 'medium-contianer' for you class instead of 'medium-container' :)

Comment: Thank you so much, it helps a ton! And I always seem to misspell container lol. I currently do not have any ways I know of to test across different devices. I am fairly new to coding. Would I need to actually have multiple devices on hand to do that or is there some sort of extension or website that I can do that on?

Comment: I'm glad it helped! At work we use Browserstack as a tool for testing code on mulitple devices & operating system.

Here is the link: https://www.browserstack.com/

Answer (score 0):

After reading the article provided by Fred, I began to debug iOS in safari and found that there was user-agent-stylesheets enforced upon my h3 tag. I changed my h3 tag to a span and altered any inconsistent CSS and solved my issue

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).